# Compare two string and count letters that are different

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

I have to write a function that takes in two strings and compares them then returns the number of letters in the strings that are different. For example "ABC" and "DEC" should return 4. My function always turns up one short because of how I am comparing them. I've looked but can't seem to find a fix.

I have tried looping through the string without splitting and ended up with the same problem.

```
function makeAnagram(a, b) {
    let result = 0;

    let a1 = a.split("").sort();
    let b1 = b.split("").sort();
    for(let i = 0; i < b1.length; i++){
        if(a1.indexOf(b1[i] < 0)){
            result += 1;
        }
    }


    return result;
 }
```

Comment: Your closing bracket is in the wrong place... `a1.indexOf(b1[i] < 0)` should be `a1.indexOf(b1[i]) < 0`.   Also, there's no need to do the `.sort()`

Comment: how the heck "ABC" and "DEC" should return 4 when there are 3 letters in each word....

Comment: @Gibor - because they're after **different** letters

Comment: @gibor they have `C` in common, so the difference is `ABDE`, which is 4 long.

Comment: oh ok, thats kinda weird way to look at it but gt his intentions, but thats not what his logic suggests. in his code he takes only the first string and tries to find its letters in the 2nd string, and increments count by 1 when it fails to find. but he should also do the opposite- take the 2nd string and find its letters in the 1st string. OR he can count the similar letters in one loop- and then subtract that from the sum of both string's lengths.

Comment: May I know what would be your result if ABCC and DEC ? Same 4 or 5?

Comment: @Narendhran it would be . I think I need to rephrase. The letters must be removed so that at the end, the words are the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line:

```
("ABC"+"DEC").split('').sort().join('').replace(/(.)\1+/g, "").length
```

Returns

```
4
```

Steps of the program:

1. `("ABC"+"DEC")` makes a string with the 2 merged words : `ABCDEC`
2. `("ABC"+"DEC").split('').sort().join('')` makes the characters sorted in the string: `ABCCDE`. This will enable us to find duplicates easily with regex
3. `replace(/(.)\1+/g, "")` removes all sequences of 2+ characters, then we get `ABDE`
4. `.length` counts the remaining characters, which are the ones with single occurence.

Comment: strange @TEbogo , I suggested [same answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58727460/2443988)

Comment: @SumitRamteke yes I saw your answer, you submitted it at least 5 minutes after mine, and mine was already accepted when you submitted yours :)

Comment: It looks very neat, but, what happens with:

```("AA"+"ZZ").split('').sort().join('').replace(/(.)\1+/g, "").length``` 

?

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

**Edited** as suggestion by [@freefaller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/930393/freefaller)

```js
const makeAnagram = (a, b) => {
  const arr1 = a.split('')
  const arr2 = b.split('')
  const diff1 = arr1.filter(letter => !arr2.includes(letter))
  const diff2 = arr2.filter(letter => !arr1.includes(letter))
  
  return diff1.length + diff2.length
}

console.log(makeAnagram('ABC', 'DEC'))
```

Comment: I was trying to write something similar, but forgot about `.includes`. Using `[...diff1, ...diff2].length` seems a bit OTT to me. Wouldn't it be simpler and quicker to just have `diff1.length + diff2.length`?

Comment: @freefaller thanks for your comment.. I have refactored as it looks better!

Answer (score 2):

An ES6 way to do the same

```js
const makeAnagram = (a, b) => new Set(a + b).size - new Set([...a].filter(x => b.includes(x))).size;
console.log(makeAnagram('ABC', 'DEC')); // prints 4
```

Comment: Thanks @MattEllen. Made that change

Answer (score 1):

This is what I would do

#### Implementation

```
let makeAnagram = (a,b) => {
  let clubStr = ('' + a).concat(b);
  let sortedStr = clubStr.trim().split('').sort().join('');
  let uncommonStr = sortedStr.replace(/(\w)\1+/gi, '');
  return uncommonStr.length;
};
```

You can do **same in one liner**.

> Caller : `makeAnagram('ABC', 'DCE')`
>
> Ouput : `4`